# How to get MandatoryStreamCombination

Tags: xamarin.android

In what should I cast "o" below to get the list of `MandatoryStreamCombination` instances in Xamarin Android ?

I keep getting InvalidCastException. I also tried Java arrays - no luck.

```
var manager = (CameraManager?)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
var cameraId = "0";

var characteristics = manager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
var o = characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.ScalerMandatoryStreamCombinations);

var msc = (MandatoryStreamCombination[]?)o; //InvalidCastException
var o1 = (Java.Lang.Object[]?)o; //InvalidCastException
var msc2 = (MandatoryStreamCombination?)o; //InvalidCastException
```

I post the android doc so you understand better.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#SCALER_MANDATORY_STREAM_COMBINATIONS

Java return value is MandatoryStreamCombination[] not MandatoryStreamCombination.

Answer (score 1):

The returned value is not an array, it's a single instance of [MandatoryStreamCombination](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/MandatoryStreamCombination), which then has a method [getStreamsInformation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/MandatoryStreamCombination#getStreamsInformation()).

So something like:

```cs
var characteristics = manager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
var o = characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.ScalerMandatoryStreamCombinations);

var msc = (MandatoryStreamCombination?)o; 
var listOfCombinations = msc.getStreamsInformation();
```

Comment: Does not work. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

From document [CameraCharacteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics+Key) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.hardware.camera2.cameracharacteristics.get?view=xamarin-),we can find that the returned value is an `Object`, so you cannot convert it to an array by using following code:

```
//var msc = (MandatoryStreamCombination[]?)o; //InvalidCastException
//var o1 = (Java.Lang.Object[]?)o; //InvalidCastException
```

For how to use the Api, you can refer to threads : [How to get id of front facing camera using Camera2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658278/how-to-get-id-of-front-facing-camera-using-camera2)  and [How to get available resolutions using CameraX on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60901831/how-to-get-available-resolutions-using-camerax-on-android). Although the code is Android-based, the usage in Xamarin Android is very similar, and we only need to convert the code.

Comment: So how do I convert it to something usable in C# ? Using Camera2, not CameraX.

Comment: Hi @Softlion, what do you want to implement and what code do you want to convert?

Comment: Does not work. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Try to use code: `var obj = (RecommendedStreamConfigurationMap?)o;`

Comment: If it is convenient for you, could you please post more code snippets so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: manager = (CameraManager?)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService); You now have the complete snippet.

Comment: I mean can you share [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can try to test on our side?